# Cómo hago que este mapa no se pueda cambiar de tamaño

Tags: javascript, html5, api

Éste es mi código:

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat:  40.940716, lng: -73.888317};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 11,
    center: myLatLng

  });

 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

}
```

El mapa esta en http://adcon-inc.com/

Comment: Hola @Enmanuel, ¡bienvenido a [es.so]! Sería recomendable que agregues mayor información en la pregunta. ¿Podrás [edit] explicando con tus palabras qué es lo que estás intentando hacer. Además, ¿podrías mostrarnos qué intentaste hasta ahora?

Comment: podrías usar una imagen, esto te logra impedir el zoom y que no se mueva el mapa, podes ver mas información  en este url https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si te refieres al zoom, lo que puedes hacer es añadir las siguientes opciones al momento de la creación del mapa:

```
disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
maxZoom: 11,
minZoom: 11,
zoomControl: false,
scrollwheel: false
```

Estas opciones desactivarán el control de zoom, el zoom al momento de hacer scroll y el zoom con el doble clic. Además también puedes añadir el máximo y mínimo zoom permitido.

Ejemplo: https://plnkr.co/edit/sm5W2ER6LsUKWgW0At5O?p=preview

Por el contrario, si lo que deseas es que el tamaño del contenedor no cambie, deberías hacerlo a través de CSS.